# WinForms and Entity Framework on a user-story basis: keeping the code readable

Tags: winforms, entity-framework

I have a WinForms application which uses Entity Framework 5.0.

I want to keep the context short-lived by instantiating and disposing it on a user-story basis. For example - user clicks save, then instantiate the context, save, and dispose.

In addition to that, I have a service layer, and I inject the same context to the services.

The issue is that I am ending up with lengthy code in each of my user-story handlers. For example:

```
void OnSaveButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    {
        var transactionService = new TransactionService(context);

        transactionService.SaveTransaction(...);
    }
}
```

So I am just wondering if there is any pattern (or DBContext's event) that I could use to keep the code "readable" for my client. Much appreciated.

Comment: FYI, it's hard to tell from your code, but you don't need to create a database transaction with EF, it creates one automatically implicitly.  Regarding your code, you haven't shown what the problem is.. the code you've shown looks nice and neat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could restructure the code by writing a function that acquires the context and the transaction, then performs your desired action. Something like:

```
// Define a new delegate to handle the various actions
public delegate void UseCasehandler(DbContext context);

void PerformUseCase(UseCaseHandler action)
{
    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    {
        var transactionService = new TransactionService(context);
        action(context);
        transactionService.SaveTransaction(...);
    }
}
```

Then your SaveButtonClick would just say

```
PerformUseCase(SaveData);
```

Where `SaveData` has the code relevant to that use case.

```
void SaveData(DbContext context)
{
    ...
}
```

Now, this doesn't do much to shorten the length of the code, but it separates the boilerplate stuff from the code doing the real work.

Re: Mystere Man's comment. If acquiring the transaction isn't necessary, then this answer is even less useful. But it might be worthwhile if it turns out there are other actions being repeated in every handler that could be moved into `PerformUseCase`.

Comment: This was really insightful, much appreciated!